# Can we re-position ほど phrase?

Tags: grammar, particle-ほど

The following are commonly-used patterns that I find in some resources.

- A: 彼は私ほどハンサムじゃない。He is not as handsome as I.
- B: 私ほどハンサムな男の人はいない。There is no man who is as handsome as I.

## Question

Is it possible to rearrange `B` so that it looks like `A` as follows.

> ハンサムな男の人は私ほどいない。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't rearrange it, since it's going to be grammatically incorrect.

In your sentence, the 私ほど is describing the subject and is part of ハンサムな男の人.

As a side note I would suggest useing ex. 他にない:

私ほどハンサムな男の人は他にいない。